# Mouse events not triggering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The issue is none of my mouse events are triggering on my Answer component.  If I call the function directly from the prop it will fire ie

```
onMouseEnter={this.hoverEnter()}
```

But nothing fires when I just pass the reference   ie

```
onMouseEnter={this.hoverEnter}
```

I'm not sure why nothing is triggering.

Is there a problem with my logic, is something not hooked up correctly?

```js
class GameStage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentCount: 3,
            showStartButton: true,
            commence: false,
            level: 1,
            question: null,
            answerSet: {
                a1: null,
                a2: null,
                a3: null,
                a4: null
            }
        }
        this.startGame = this.startGame.bind(this);
        this.hoverEnter = this.hoverEnter.bind(this);
        this.hoverLeave = this.hoverLeave.bind(this);
    }

    startGame() {
        this.setState({showStartButton: false, commence: true});
        console.log(this.state.answerSet)
    }

    clickHandle () {
        console.log("clicked")
    }

    hoverEnter () {
        console.log("mouse enter")
    }

    hoverLeave () {
        console.log("mouse leave")
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className={classes.GameStage}>
                {this.state.commence ?
                    <div className={classes.AnswerContainer}>
                        <Answer 
                            onClick={this.clickHandle}
                            onMouseOver={this.hoverEnter} 
                            onMouseLeave={this.hoverLeave} 
                            correct={false}>
                            {this.state.answerSet.a1}
                        </Answer>
                        <Answer 
                            correct={false}>
                            {this.state.answerSet.a2}
                        </Answer>
                        <Answer correct={false}>{this.state.answerSet.a3}</Answer>
                        <Answer correct={false}>{this.state.answerSet.a4}</Answer>
                    </div>
                : null }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default GameStage;
```

Here is the answer component

```js
import React from 'react';

import classes from './Answer.css';

const answer = (props) => (
    <div className={classes.Answer} correct={props.value}>{props.children}</div>
)

export default answer;
```

Comment: Do you handle the `onMouseEnter` prop in your `Answer` component?

Comment: No everything is taken care of in the gamestage  component.. 

I'll edit and add the answer component

Comment: dont you need to encapsulate the attribute value in an arrow function in order for it to retain its proper scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `onMouseEnter` prop given to your `Answer` component so that it will be called when the mouse enters the `div` in `Answer`. This is true for all the other mouse events as well.

```
const Answer = (props) => (
  <div
    className={classes.Answer}
    correct={props.value}
    onMouseEnter={props.onMouseEnter}
  >
    {props.children}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Answer` component needs to pass the event handlers into the underlying HTML in order for them to do anything. So the `Answer` component might look something like:

```
import React from 'react';

import classes from './Answer.css';

const answer = (props) => (
    <div className={classes.Answer} onClick={props.onClick} onMouseOver={props.onMouseOver} onMouseLeave={props.onMouseLeave} correct={props.value}>{props.children}</div>
)

export default answer;
```

You also have other issues - you seem to mix up `props.value` with `props.correct`. You might want to consider propType validation. As it currently stands, your handlers will also not work as expected if they try to access `this` because you have not bound your context.